# Would the small toy piggy on my desk be unpleasant for my Muslim co-workers?

Tags: pork

I know they are not allowed to eat the pig but this one is clearly not edible; it is a small plastic toy for decoration given by a friend from another room. It appears externally rather cute.

Would a plastic pig on my table be a problem for co-workers? It is not very important to me so in case it is, I would rather remove it from my table.

Comment: Thanks for caring about your coworkers, I think it is a personal matter so just ask him, personally I would say it is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry . Real pigs are najis to touch and haram to eat for Muslims, not the toy pig.